# Connecting to Mongo Atlas from Digital Ocean Ubuntu Droplet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, digital-ocean

I have a node app which connects to a MongoDB shard on Atlas.  This all works fine when I'm developing locally but when I deploy to Digital Ocean droplet I get a connection error.

I have opened the required port via ufw:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

The code to initiate the connection is:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE).then(
  ()=>{
    console.log("connected to mongoDB")},
 (err)=>{
     console.log("err",err);
})
```

but I get the error message:

```
    err { MongoNetworkError: connection 3 to myapp-shard-00-00- 
      jooao.mongodb.net:27017 closed
      at TLSSocket.<anonymous
 (/home/stuart/apps/myapp.co.uk/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:275:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:422:20)
    at _handle.close (net.js:541:12)
    at TCP.done [as _onclose] (_tls_wrap.js:379:7)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',

  message: 'connection 3 to myapp-shard-00-00-jooao.mongodb.net:27017 closed' }
```

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `27017` port refers to the "server" and not the machine where your application is running on. MongoDB Atlas instances typically will not use the default port anyway and will be "something else" which is identified on the connection sting obtainable from your Atlas console. Provided there is nothing else blocking the communication on the application instance, then the other cause aside from correct address will most likely be the allowed whitelisted IP addresses by the Atlas cluster itself. These can be configured in the Atlas console.

Comment: thanks @NeilLunn I'll take a look when I get back from work

Comment: @StuartBrown did you find the issue?